# Vectorize find function in a for loop

Tags: algorithm, matlab, vectorization

I have the following code which outputs the values of `array1` that are less than or equal to each element of `array2`.  The two arrays are not the same length.  This for loop is pretty slow since the arrays are large (`~500,000` elements).  FYI, both arrays are always in ascending order.

Any help making this a vector operation and speeding it up would be appreciated.

I was considering some kind of multi-step process of `interp1()` with the 'nearest' option. Then finding where the corresponding `outArray` was larger than `array2` and then fixing points somehow ... but I thought there had to be a better way.

```
array2 = [5 6 18 25];
array1 = [1 5 9 15 22 24 31];
outArray = nan(size(array2));
for a =1:numel(array2)
    outArray(a) = array1(find(array1 <= array2(a),1,'last'));
end
```

returns:

```
outArray =    
     5     5    15    24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible vectorization:

```
[~,idx] = max(cumsum(bsxfun(@le, array1', array2)));
outArray = array1(idx);
```

---

## EDIT:

In recent editions, and thanks to JIT compilations, MATLAB has gotten pretty good at executing good old non-vectorized loops.

Below is some code similar to yours that takes advantage of the fact that the two arrays are sorted (thus if `pos(a) = find(array1<=array2(a), 1, 'last')` then we are guaranteed that `pos(a+1)` computed at the next iteration will be no less than the previous `pos(a)`)

```
pos = 1;
idx = zeros(size(array2));
for a=1:numel(array2)
    while pos <= numel(array1) && array1(pos) <= array2(a)
        pos = pos + 1;
    end
    idx(a) = pos-1;
end
%idx(idx==0) = [];      %# in case min(array2) < min(array1)
outArray = array1(idx);
```

*Note: The commented line handles the case when the minimum value of `array2` is less than the minimum value of `array1` (i.e when `find(array1<=array2(a))` is empty)*

I performed a comparison between all the methods posted so far, and this is indeed the fastest one. The timings (performed using the [TIMEIT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function) function) for vectors of length N=5000 were:

```
0.097398     # your code
0.39127      # my first vectorized code
0.00043361   # my new code above
0.0016276    # Mohsen Nosratinia's code
```

and here are the timings for N=500000:

```
(? too-long) # your code
(out-of-mem) # my first vectorized code
0.051197     # my new code above
0.25206      # Mohsen Nosratinia's code
```

.. a pretty good improvement from the initial 10 minutes you reported down to 0.05 second!

Here is the test code if you are want to reproduce the results:

```
function [t,v] = test_array_find()
    %array2 = [5 6 18 25];
    %array1 = [1 5 9 15 22 24 31];
    N = 5000;
    array1 = sort(randi([100 1e6], [1 N]));
    array2 = sort(randi([min(array1) 1e6], [1 N]));

    f = {...
        @() func1(array1,array2);   %# Aero Engy
        @() func2(array1,array2);   %# Amro
        @() func3(array1,array2);   %# Amro
        @() func4(array1,array2);   %# Mohsen Nosratinia
    };

    t = cellfun(@timeit, f);
    v = cellfun(@feval, f, 'UniformOutput',false);
    assert( isequal(v{:}) )
end

function outArray = func1(array1,array2)
    %idx = arrayfun(@(a) find(array1<=a, 1, 'last'), array2);
    idx = zeros(size(array2));
    for a=1:numel(array2)
        idx(a) = find(array1 <= array2(a), 1, 'last');
    end
    outArray = array1(idx);
end

function outArray = func2(array1,array2)
    [~,idx] = max(cumsum(bsxfun(@le, array1', array2)));
    outArray = array1(idx);
end

function outArray = func3(array1,array2)
    pos = 1;
    lastPos = numel(array1);
    idx = zeros(size(array2));
    for a=1:numel(array2)
        while pos <= lastPos && array1(pos) <= array2(a)
            pos = pos + 1;
        end
        idx(a) = pos-1;
    end
    %idx(idx==0) = [];      %# in case min(array2) < min(array1)
    outArray = array1(idx);
end

function outArray = func4(array1,array2)
    [~,I] = sort([array1 array2]);
    a1size = numel(array1);
    J = find(I>a1size);
    outArray = nan(size(array2));
    for k=1:numel(J),
        if  I(J(k)-1)<=a1size,
            outArray(k) = array1(I(J(k)-1));
        else
            outArray(k) = outArray(k-1);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but due the large size of the arrays this causes an out of memory error.  FYI, running on a Linux server with 16GB of memory

Comment: I figured it would happen. Vectorization usually comes at the price of increased memory usage (the above code will build an intermediary matrix of size `numel(array1)-by-numel(array2)`, which in your case is about 18GB!)... how does your current code perform on the full data, can you provide some timings?

Comment: It takes about 10 minutes for array1 of (1x223700) and array2 of (1x223100). Using an interp1(array1,array1,array2,'nearest') takes about 0.4 seconds.  However, about 50% of it is wrong as it picks some points larger than array2.  I need something like interp1(...'lessthan') but that doesn't exist :)

Comment: @Amro Funny that I also posted a similar solution 10min ago. Seems that I'm not the only sleepless coder tonight :-)

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia: I know, I just refreshed my page :) Sorry my benchmark contains your old code!

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia: since both our codes are doing the same thing (a single-pass through the array), I guess they will time similar, so no point in updating the benchmark now..

Answer (score 2):

One reason for it being slow is that you are comparing all elements in `array1` with all elements in `array2` so if they contain `M` and `N` elements, respectively, the complexity is `O(M*N)`. However, since the arrays are already sorted there is a linear-time, `O(M+N)`, solution for it

```
array2 = [5 6 18 25];
array1 = [1 5 9 15 22 24 31];

outArray = nan(size(array2));
k1 = 1;
n1 = numel(array1);
n2 = numel(array2);

ks = 1;
while ks <= n2 && array2(ks) < array1(1)
    ks = ks + 1;
end

for k2=ks:n2
    while k1 < n1 && array2(k2) >= array1(k1+1) 
        k1 = k1+1;
    end
    outArray(k2) = array1(k1);
end
```

Here is a test case to measure the time it takes for each method to run for two arrays of length 500,000.

```
array2 = 1:500000;
array1 = array2-1;

tic
outArray1 = nan(size(array2));
k1 = 1;
n1 = numel(array1);
n2 = numel(array2);

ks = 1;
while ks <= n2 && array2(ks) < array1(1)
    ks = ks + 1;
end

for k2=ks:n2
    while k1 < n1 && array2(k2) >= array1(k1+1) 
        k1 = k1+1;
    end
    outArray1(k2) = array1(k1);
end
toc    

tic
outArray2 = nan(size(array2));
for a =1:numel(array2)
    outArray2(a) = array1(find(array1 <= array2(a),1,'last'));
end
toc
```

And the result is

```
Elapsed time is 0.067637 seconds.
Elapsed time is 418.458722 seconds.
```

Comment: ha, looks like we were thinking alike. I posted something similar :)

Comment: Now you have refernced to my old solution that I deleted. I'm gonna undelete that and add a note to it.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** *This was my initial solution and is the one that is benchmarked in Amro's answer. However, it is slower than the linear-time solution that I provided in my other answer.*

One reason for it being slow is that you are comparing all elements in `array1` with all elements in `array2` so if they contain `M` and `N` elements the complexity is `O(M*N)`. However, you can concatenate them and sort them together and get faster algorithm of complexity `(M+N)*log2(M+N)`. Here is one way of doing it:

```
array2 = [5 6 18 25];
array1 = [1 5 9 15 22 24 31];

[~,I] = sort([array1 array2]);
a1size = numel(array1);
J = find(I>a1size);
outArray = nan(size(array2));
for k=1:numel(J),
    if  I(J(k)-1)<=a1size,
        outArray(k) = array1(I(J(k)-1));
    else
        outArray(k) = outArray(k-1);
    end
end

disp(outArray)

% Test using original code
outArray = nan(size(array2));
for a =1:numel(array2)
    outArray(a) = array1(find(array1 <= array2(a),1,'last'));
end
disp(outArray)
```

The concatenated array will be

```
>> [array1 array2]
ans =
     1     5     9    15    22    24    31     5     6    18    25
```

and

```
>> [B,I] = sort([array1 array2])
B =
     1     5     5     6     9    15    18    22    24    25    31
I =
     1     2     8     9     3     4    10     5     6    11     7
```

It shows that in sorted array `B` the first `5` comes from second position in concatenated array and second 5 from eight position, and so on. So to find the largest element in `array1` that is smaller than a given element in `array2` we just need to go through all indices in `I` that are larger than the size of `array1` (therefore belonging to `array2`) and go back and find closest index belonging to `array1`. `J` contains the position of these elements in vector `I`:

```
>> J = find(I>a1size)
J =
     3     4     7    10
```

Now the for loop goes through these indices and checks if in `I` the index right before each index referenced from `J` belongs to `array1`or not. If it belongs to `array1` it retrieves it value from `array1` otherwise it copies the value found for previous index.

Note that both your code and this code fails if `array2` contains an element that is smaller than the smallest element in `array1`.